# Clojure - how exactly symbols are evaluated?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, macros, symbols

We know clojure evaluates (+ 1 1) in couple of stages from reading the unicode characters to actual evaluation of the reader output...

In code, that looks something like 
 `(eval (read-string "(+ 1 1)"))`

However it hurts my brain **when `('+ '1 '2)` (or `('+ 1 2)`) gives me 2.**...

core> (def something ('+ '1 '2)) 
#'alcamii4hr.core/something 
core> (type something) 
java.lang.Long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symbols, like keywords, can be invoked like functions. When invoked, they both do the same thing, look themselves up in what they presume to be a map. They have two arities `[a-map]` and `[a-map not-found]`.

```
;; not-found defaults to nil
('foo {'bar 42}) ;=> nil

('foo {'foo 42}) ;=> 42

;; not-found can also be supplied in the arity-2 case
('foo {'bar 42} :not-found) ;=> :not-found
```

In your specific case, it just assumes that the first argument is something associative, and doesn't check. It can't find the symbol `+` in what it presumes to be a map, so it returns the not-found value: `2`.

```
('+ '1) ;=> nil     ; not-found

('+ '1 '2) ;=> 2    ; because 2 is the not-found values

('+ '1 '2 '3) ;=> clojure.lang.ArityException
```

To see how this all fits together, you can check the [invoke method on the symbol class](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Symbol.java#L125),
which calls [clojure.RT.get](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L748), which is what looks something up in an associative thing. This is the same method called by [clojure.core/get](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L1491).

In clourescript, this works the same way, but is implemented differently. (In clojurescript itself, and not in the host language.) You can read about that [here](http://blog.klipse.tech/clojure/2016/04/07/ifn.html).